# I want to be able to reuse Chip components made with Svelte

Tags: components, svelte

It is difficult to reuse the Chip components that are currently running in my project.
I would like to modify the code to make it easier to reuse.

[image]

[image]

For example, I want to make it as easy to use as this

```
let labels=["foo", "bar"];

<Chips labels="{labels}" >
```

Current source code

```
<script>
import { redirectUris } from '../../store/';
import close from '../../asset/icon/tip/close.svg';

function removeFromList(index) {
  $redirectUris.splice(index, 1);
  $redirectUris = $redirectUris;
}
</script>

<div class="chips">
  {#each $redirectUris as uri, index}
    <div class="chip">
      <p class="chip-name">{uri}</p>
      <button
        on:click="{() => {
          console.log(uri);
          removeFromList(index);
          console.log($redirectUris);
        }}">
        <img src="{close}" alt="close" />
      </button>
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the reference to your store and replace it with a property:

```svelte
<script>
import close from '../../asset/icon/tip/close.svg';

export let labels = [];
</script>

<div class="chips">
  {#each labels as label, index}
    <div class="chip">
      <p class="chip-name">{label}</p>
      <button
        on:click="{() => {
          labels.splice(index, 1);
          labels = labels;
        }}">
        <img src="{close}" alt="close" />
      </button>
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```

You can then use it like you posted above. If you need to update the chips in your parent component, use `bind` which establishes a two-way binding:

```svelte
<script>
import Chips from '..';
let labels=["foo", "bar"];
</script>

<Chips bind:labels />
```

If you need a "chip deleted" event, you can use event dispatchers for that: https://svelte.dev/docs#createEventDispatcher

```svelte
<script>
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
import close from '../../asset/icon/tip/close.svg';

export let labels = [];
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
</script>

<div class="chips">
  {#each labels as label, index}
    <div class="chip">
      <p class="chip-name">{label}</p>
      <button
        on:click="{() => {
          labels.splice(index, 1);
          labels = labels;
          dispatch('close', { label, index });
        }}">
        <img src="{close}" alt="close" />
      </button>
    </div>
  {/each}
</div>
```